# WCF SERVICE gives us faulted response

Tags: wcf, sql-server-2008

My service is hosted on IIS7, windows 2008 server with sql server2008 express.

I am getting following error when the process takes more than 2 minutes i got this response, i m unable to find out either it is due to sql server time out or wcf time out. my sql server process is also took long.
An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to http://REMOTE/SynchronizationService_test/SyncService.svc. This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have set the mode of service singleton and it works for me.
And also set configuration Throtling of WCF behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the best thing to do is to look through the server logs, as the message suggests.
Learn how to configure WCF tracing: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx